# Need current time to YouTube video play

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I have an extension I'm working on. I need the time of the YouTube video playing in the tab.

This is my code but it's not working? Any ideas?

```
var videoTime = document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-time-current');
var timeField = document.getElementById('timeStamp');
timeField.value = videoTime.nodeValue;
```

Is it because is it not an embedded video?

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my firefox extension

```
var ytVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];  `  
ytVideo.currentTime; //output in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("movie_player").getCurrentTime();
```

Comment: Hmm if I only want this to occur on youtube pages then I need to put this code into a content script rather than background?

Comment: @user3912082 Yeah, this code should run in the content script. But if you require it in the `background.js` you can send a message from the content script using [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).